# Passing unmanaged pointer to unmanaged object in managed class in C++/CLI

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, unmanaged, mixed-mode, unmanaged-memory

Let's assume the following situation:

```
class A
{
public:
  void MyMethod()
  {
    a->AnotherMethod(b);
  }
private:
  MyType* a;
  MyAnotherType* b;
};
```

and

```
typedef std::vector< int >MyAnotherType;
```

I want to pass a pointer to std::vector allocated (and filled in) in C++/CLI code to unmanaged C++. If I simply write `a->AnotherMethod(b)` then the vector is empty in unmanaged code (e.g. 4 elements in C++/CLI and 0 elements after passing to `a`.

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: There's too much code missing here to say for sure what's wrong.  Is the unmanaged C++ code part of the same module as the C++/CLI code calling it, or are you trying to pass STL collections across DLL boundaries (a very bad idea)?

Comment: @Ben, yes, exactly I wanted to pass STL collection between DLLs. Finally I gave up and made a pin_ptr workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [pragma managed and unmanaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Make sure the definition of the class you are passing into the DLL is defined in unmanaged section.